# Is there a way to use multiple System.Web.Mvc.RemoteAttributes? Getting "Duplicate RemoteAttribute attribute."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-validation

I need to perform two separate validations on a view model property. Apparently, RemoteAttribute can only be applied once per property.  This is probably a stupid question, but does anyone know a way around this?

```
public class ForgotPasswordModel
{
    // Getting compiler error "Duplicate RemoteAttribute attribute"
    [Remote("CanFindEmail", "Account", ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailNotFound", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    [Remote("IsAccountVerified", "Account", ErrorMessageResourceName = "AccountByEmailNotVerified", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PropertyRequired")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resx), Name = "PersonEmailAddress")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way around this (since `RemoteAttribute` does not support multiple declarations per property) without rewriting how MVC handles remote validation. A single Remote attribute should point at a method on the server that performs all remote validation. You should aggregate multiple validation types in that server method. The reason why you don't want multiple remote attributes per property is performance, as every additional callback would have overhead.

Comment: This is unfortunate because I need to be able to have specific error methods for the two validations...

Comment: You can always have a single method that calls both of your validation methods.

Comment: Returning specific error messages has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000495/asp-net-mvc-3-remote-validation-set-custom-error-message