# MVC 3 Check for Duplicates before saving to DB, display duplicate error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to check for duplicates before saving to the database in the create and edit methods inside my controller. Then I need to display a duplicate error message instead of a generic error message.

My definition of a duplicate is:
userid + Code1ID + Code2ID + Code3ID + Code4ID.

Question:
How to check for a duplicate when the combination of the values above already exists?

**Table Name**

```
 Character:
CharacterID int 
UserID int
Code1ID int
Code2ID int
Code3ID int
Code4ID int
Name Varchar(40)
```

My primary key is composed of UserID + Code1ID + Code2ID + Code3ID + Code4ID.
This guarantees that no duplicates are entered into the database. But the error message I am returning is a general error message.

I need to check for duplicates first and then return a warning message or error message based on the duplication alone.

**Here is the edit methods inside the controller**

```
  //
        // GET: /Character/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Character character = db.Characters.Find(id);
        PopulateUserIDDropDownList(character.UserID);
            PopulateCode1IDDropDownList(character.Code1ID);
            PopulateCode2IDDropDownList(character.Code2ID);
            PopulateCode3IDDropDownList(character.Code3ID);
            PopulateCode4IDDropDownList(character.Code4ID);
            return View(character);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Character/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Character character)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Entry(character).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Generic Error. Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
            }
        PopulateUserIDDropDownList(character.UserID);
            PopulateCode1IDDropDownList(character.Code1ID);
            PopulateCode2IDDropDownList(character.Code2ID);
            PopulateCode3IDDropDownList(character.Code3ID);
            PopulateCode4IDDropDownList(character.Code4ID);
            return View(character);
        }
```

**Here is the create methods inside the controller**

```
    //
    // GET: /Character/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
    PopulateUserIDDropDownList();
        PopulateCode1IDDropDownList();
        PopulateCode2IDDropDownList();
        PopulateCode3IDDropDownList();
        PopulateCode4IDDropDownList();
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Character/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Character character)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Characters.Add(character);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Generic Error.Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
        }
    PopulateUserIDDropDownList(character.UserID);
        PopulateCode1IDDropDownList(character.Code1ID);
        PopulateCode2IDDropDownList(character.Code2ID);
        PopulateCode3IDDropDownList(character.Code3ID);
        PopulateCode4IDDropDownList(character.Code4ID);
        return View(character);
    }
```

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace myproject.Models
{
    public class Character
    {
        [Key]
        public int CharacterID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "User")]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Code1 is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Code1")]
        public int Code1ID { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Code2 is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Code2")]
        public int Code2ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Code3 is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Code3")]
        public int Code3ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Code4 is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Code4")]
        public int Code4ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "level is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Level")]
        public int LevelID { get; set; }

        public virtual aspnet_Users Aspnet_User { get; set; }
        public virtual Code1 Code1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Code2 Code2 { get; set; }
        public virtual Code3 Code3 { get; set; }
        public virtual Code4 Code4 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I guess the title says it all: MVC 3 Check for Duplicates before saving to DB, display duplicate error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before saving to DB... search the DB with those values... if you find something... you have a duplicate and you can display the correct message.

When you are editing, you need to exclude for the query the current object being edited.

You can do a Count() on your repository with those IDs as the WHERE part... if result is 1 or more... you have duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `remote` attribute to your column on which you want to check duplicate. you may see the an example [here](http://www.aaronstannard.com/post/2010/12/07/remote-validation-asp-net-mvc3.aspx). You can also customize the error message depending upon the logic as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000495/asp-net-mvc-3-remote-validation-set-custom-error-message?rq=1). you may need to add another field in viewmodel having the complete key and then add remote attribute on it. If you want single message then you may need custom model binder describe [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx). or as said above add another field containing concatenated value of key and add remote attribute to that field and enable `validationsummary`

Comment: Seems like remoting works best for 1 value. But my definition of a duplicate is userid + Code1ID + Code2ID + Code3ID + Code4ID. All displayed in drop downs

Comment: You don't happen to have a link to an example. I am new to MVC 3

Comment: For custom modelbinder link is there for combining field you need to set the property as given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758734/how-can-i-combine-two-fields-in-a-selectlist-text-description